# My navbar stop working correctly for Ruby on Rails - Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml, navbar

I stepped away from my computer and came back to an issue with the navbar. It was working correctly and now its not. The individual tabs within the navigational bar still work but it doesn't show what tab is active. The About Us tab remains in bold (active) eventhough I might be on the Home, Browse, or Start page. I'm not sure what to do to fix this problem. The code for the navbar is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
        .span2
            = link_to image_tag("company_logo.png", class: "brand", style: "margin-top: 10px;"), static_pages_home_page_path
        .span7
            %ul.nav.nav-tabs
                %li.active#about
                    = link_to "About Us", static_pages_about_path, id: "about"
                %li#browse
                    = link_to "Browse", static_pages_browse_path, id: "browse"
                %li#start
                    = link_to "Start", static_pages_start_project_path, id: "start"
                %li#blog                    
                    = link_to "Blog", '#', id: "blog"
```

Comment: How do you switch the `active` class between `li`s?

Comment: you have given the id to the anchor as well as to the li. this could be a problem if you select the element by id

Comment: @JuriGlass I'm fairly new to RoR. Are you referring to the li.active or are you saying I should add an anchor element to the code above?

Comment: I took the active off of the about tab and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'active' phrase was removed from the About Us tab. This removed the anchor from the navbar. Thanks to @Juri Glass and RobHeaton.

```
        %ul.nav.nav-tabs
            %li.active#about
                = link_to "About Us", static_pages_about_path, id: "about"
            %li#browse
                = link_to "Browse", static_pages_browse_path, id: "browse"
            %li#start
                = link_to "Start", static_pages_start_project_path, id: "start"
            %li#blog                    
                = link_to "Blog", '#', id: "blog"
```